# apt-get cant find locate package, how to find correct mirror/repository of the package?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am trying to install package libfabric1, and I've perform apt-get update but still no success.

So I think the reason apt-get can't locate package may due to the repository not listed in the /etc/apt/sources.list.

So given a package, how do I know which repository to add in my sources.list ?

Comment: I don't see the package available for 14.04 (trusty) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libfabric1

Comment: If you want to add a repo you're better off going through the 'Software & Updates' application > Other Software as it's less error prone.  As for finding a repo that contains it, you can try searching the interwebs if it's not in any of the standard Ubuntu repos already.  Just be careful with 3rd party repos.

Comment: I am using the ubuntu 16.04, so my question is really (newbie), say, I want to install package pmdk, and my apt-cache shows nothing, how do I proceed next ? On the installation tutorial, it seems like this can be done through apt-get, so I assume there is a repository for this package ?

Comment: Your question states 14.04 and not 16.04.  If you're asking a new question, it should be put as a new question and not a comment.  The link I provided can be used to search the database of available packages needing only a browser & no command knowledge (you can of course search by commands, but browser is newbie friendly albeit slower)

Comment: let's say I found the libfabric1 package here : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/libfabric1   it's under bionic, what should I do next so I can install it from apt-get ?

Comment: Install a bionic (18.04) package on a 14.04 system is not advisable for a newbie.  If you look at that page it'll force the dependencies to be upgraded too, which may create a mess of a system .  This is beyond a newbie level, and 14.04 will EOL next month, so you'll be upgrading anyway soon if not moving to 14.04 ESM

Comment: so what should I proceed then ? This dependency is pre-requirement for package pmdk, which I am trying to install.

Comment: The earliest supported release of Ubuntu with `libfabric1` is 18.04. Same story for the `pmdk-tools` package. It is generally unwise to try to install a wrong-version package - doing so may break your system quite horribly. Consider upgrading your older system to 18.04 if you want the install to be easy.